# Alternative way of correctly classifying Landsat images

Tags: classification, landsat-8, land-cover, land-classification

I am conducting a supervised classification of Landsat 8 image. I have 6 classes: river, forest, built-up, brush land, grassland, and agricultural land. I assessed the spectral separability of each class and found out that it is difficult to distinguish brush land from forest and grassland from agricultural land. The classified image also showed a lot of misclassified Built-up pixels. I tried using band ratios and incorporating DEM to enhance the classification, but it did not improve, for instance kappa value is just around 0.30. I have a validated basemap (shapefile) where I based whether the areas are correctly classified. My question is, is it acceptable to clip/subset 2 classes together (say forest and grassland; river and built-up; agri land and brush land), which I know have a relatively more distinguished spectral values, then classify each group containing 2 classes, and join all classes together via mosaic tool?

I got more accurate results this way, but I wonder if this is a scientifically valid method.

Comment: What research question are you ultimately trying to answer with your land cover classification? Do you have access to LiDAR data for your AOI? Check out this repo I have been working on. It incorporates image segmentation and a variety of derived metrics: https://github.com/redfoxgis/image-segmentation-classification/blob/main/image_segmentation_classification.ipynb. Hopefully, this will give you some new techniques that you can try out.

Comment: I will be using the output from land cover classification as an input for fragmentation analysis. I don’t have access to LIDAR data.

Comment: Are you interested primarily in two classes: forested and non-forested for the fragmentation analysis?

Comment: I will be analyzing all classes. So it is important for me to classify the areas correctly as much as possible. I got more accurate results when I separately run a classification on groups of 2 classes as I mentioned above, since I minimize some areas with less distinct spectral values. Then I am thinking of joining all the classes together using mosaic tool, so I’ll end up having a landcover map with 6 classes. My problem is I don’t know if this has been done before, and whether this is acceptable or how should it be appropriately described.

Comment: If your analysis requires that you analyze all of the classes, then you should not be grouping classes such as forest and grassland. This may increase the accuracy for the land cover classification, but it will decrease the accuracy and validity of your fragmentation analysis. Have you tried incorporating texture metrics into your classification? e.g. https://evansmurphy.wixsite.com/evansspatial/arcgis-gradient-metrics-toolbox